# Placeholder For SQLite table In PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a query I would like to use that I would like to be reused for other select queries.
Is it possible to have a select query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id = ?;
```

And then bind the values like this:

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindValue(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The problem is when I do this I get this `$database->errorInfo()` from a PDOException

> HY000 1 near "?" syntax error.

I have tried taking out the table placeholder and it does work. Is it possible to do it my way or do I need to have separate functions?

Comment: Why can't you just set them as variables? `SELECT * FROM $strTable WHERE id = $iID;`

Comment: I don't think thats the way its done in PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**.

---

Long answer:

Refer to the [PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php) manual. There is a statement: `This must be a valid SQL statement for the target database server.` This means that your DB backend have to support prepared statement syntax that you use.

As far as I know, neither mysql, nor any other DB does not allow binding variables to occur in `FROM` clause. The reason for that lays deep in the concept of prepared statement. Prepared statement is being *prepared* inside the DB when you are calling `prepare`. This means that DB planner **builds a plan** for the query, so it can be executed multiple times with different parameters *without building it again and again*. To build a plan, planner needs to know affected tables, functions called, opportunities to use different fetch and join strategies (index scans/nested loops/etc.) and so on.

So, you cant 'bind' table name into prepared statement at the moment you want it to run, because DB needs table names at the moment when you `prepare` the statement. That's why you receive that message: DB requires **all** table names to be present in the preparing query.

Comment: Sure. Btw, regarding the first comment to your question. It's almost the way how it's done in PHP. It should be `SELECT * FROM $strTable WHERE id = ?`. This will actually be transformed into something like `select * from Table where id=?` and this is a valid prepared statement. But make sure that `$strTable` is not taken from user input, as taking it from input it will make your system vulnerable to SQL-injections.

Comment: Yea decided to make separate queries for each thing. Don't want no injection!